# Unique word count on selected word in file python

Tags: python, python-2.7

With Python 2.7 I open an external file which contains:

```
Text another word1
Lorem ipsem word1 something
hello first word2 post
```

I want to perform an unique count on the word `word` only, not on the 3rd row.

Desired output:

```
$ script.py
2x word1
1x word2
```

What I got so far but fails..:

```
import os
import sys
from collections import Counter

with open('./file.txt', 'r') as file:
        for item in file:
            if '.sh' in item:
                    all = item.split()[2]
                    print Counter(all.split())
```

Comment: What you want all text starting with `word` and their count ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey If you want to print all the words starting with `word` here is the code

```
import os
import sys

occurenceDict = {}
with open('./file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:  # reading each line of the file
        for word in line.split():  # splitting the line into words
           if word.find('word') != -1: # find the occurrence of word
                if word in occurenceDict: # check if word in dict
                    occurenceDict[word] += 1
                else:
                    occurenceDict[word] = 1

for word in occurenceDict:
    print str(occurenceDict[word])+'x'+" "+word
```

**Output:**

```
2x word1
1x word2
```

Comment: This one seems to be working! Thanks. Looks quite complicated tho.
I will study each word and character to understand the code.

Comment: I will edit the answer for simplicity. If you find it useful please upvote and mark accept :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to count the number of occurence of a specified word in a plain text file.

For that, I'd recommend turning the text file to a list of words

```
f = open("yourfile.txt","r") # Open the file
txt = f.read()               # read it
f.close()                    # always close it
a1 = txt.split("\n")         # split each line
a2 = []                      # create an empty array
for i in a1:                 # for each line
  a2 += a1.split(" ")        # append every word
```

And then simply use

```
a2.count("yourword")
```

You can try that [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzy/KKVYwVYhWiknP0dJR0EpOSMxswjESM9JLC4GMTJzE9NTUaTy8vPAAoZGxigqoUagUhDtsVwFRZl5JRoKYAv1kvNLQRywGgVNBc3//wE)

Comment: Receiving:     a2 += a1.split(" ")        # append every word
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain

f = open('datafile.txt').readlines()

f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in f]

f = list(chain(*f))

new = {i:f.count(i) for i in f if "word" in i}

for a, b in new.items():
    print str(b)+"x"+" "+a
```